# Valgrind / Helgrind falsely reporting TTAS pattern as race

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, valgrind

I think I've found a pretty wide class of false positives returned by the Helgrind tool. Perhaps this has been documented elsewhere, but it appears that Helgrind tool will always falsely detect the [Test and Test-And-Set pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_and_Test-and-set) as a false positive.

```
struct resource {
    int in_use;
    int value;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
}

// assume each member of resource is initialized in the main function
// in_use is initialized to zero
// value is initialized to zero
// and the lock is initialized with pthread_mutex_init() 
struct resource[1000];

void insertIntoUnused(int toInsert) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (resource[i].in_use == 0) {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&resource[i].lock);
            if (resource[i].in_use == 0) {
                resource[i].in_use = 1;
                resource[i].value = toInsert;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource[i].lock);
                return;
            }
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource[i].lock);
        }
    }
}
```

If many threads run the `insertIntoUnused` function above, Helgrind will detect a possible race condition on the first read of the `in_use` variable. However, the `in_use` variable is checked again after acquiring the lock, and the `in_use` variable is only ever *written* to when the lock is acquired.

The TTAS pattern is a super-common way of decreasing lock contention. I'm surprised that Helgrind can't "support" this pattern.

I understand why the Helgrind algorithm is detecting a race condition here. There isn't a `happens-before` relation between every read of the `in_use` variable and every write. Yet it is not difficult to prove the above code correct (I haven't actually typed it out... so, the typos aside, it is pretty-well established in the literature).

How do I get Helgrind to stop considering the first check a potential race condition so that I can find other race conditions in my program?

Comment: "Yet it is not difficult to prove" actually I'd like to see the proof, considering that the code is indeed broken as-is ;) This is pretty much the doubly checked locking pattern in an array and it's very well proven in the literature how that's broken. [E.g. this here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html) for java but same things apply to c++. Your wiki link is talking about a cpu instruction which would only useful here if you don't mind threads seeing uninitialized variables (I doubt that)

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't thought of the Java case or the C++ class variable case. It appears, however, that the site you linked says that the issue is that the assignment of the class property could happen before the constructor of the `Helper` object is finished. That's very obvious. AFAIK, the "constructor" of an int is atomic, and therefore this does not apply to situation that Helgrind is complaining about.

Comment: I should also probably note that the page you linked confirms that it works for 32-bit primitives in the JVM as well, since writes of that size are atomic (apparently).

Comment: Even writes that can be done *atomically* are not guaranteed to be done in program order (but that's not actually the issue here, since in this case the program writes to `in_use` before `value`, so readers of `value` are clearly going to have to take the lock in any case.)

Comment: @Ryan The problem is simple: Assume T1 enters first and gets until `resource[0].in_use = 1;`. At this time T2 enters sees that `resource[0].in_use == 1` and happily starts using `resource[0].value` which is still unitialized. Since you wrote the code wrongly to begin with, we don't even have to get to any compiler/CPU reorderings of the two writes, but obviously those would be possible. Now if you always only write and never read you're fine for ints (assuming atomicity which the C standard doesn't guarantee), but I assume someone will have to read too and then we have a problem.

Comment: I see. Your complaint is that I haven't initialized my variables. Since the nature of the question clearly applies to parallelism, and since the bug you point out would also apply to serial code, let's go ahead and assume that the variables are initialized. I've added a comment to make this more clear.

Comment: Also, back to the Java case for a moment -- if you make the non-primitive resource volatile, then double-checking works. It is even noted on the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Ryan No it's not about the missing initialization, the point is if any code actually tries to *read* it can read a variable that hasn't been set by the writing thread yet (a problem that doesn't exist for the given Java code, but would be just as applicable - you are after all trying to write 2 ints and not just 1). Even if no other thread ever reads from the array or only after synchronization, there's no guarantee whatsoever in C that a write to int is atomic.

Comment: Sure. An int write might not be atomic because of cache coherency or something. Please describe your error case. I'm sure you agree that all the `in_use` variables start at 0. Let's assume that some thread reads the `in_use` variable while another thread is in the middle of writing to it. *Regardless of what is read*, the code will still preform correctly. I'm starting to be pretty confident that there is no race here, just undefined behavior, as described in caf's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The POSIX threading model says that the unsynchronised access to `resource.in_use` results in undefined behaviour, regardless of the fact that in this case it "seems OK".

In theory a compiler could take advantage of that - for example, once an execution of the loop has seen `resource.in_use` as non-zero it doesn't need to test it again, because (absent a data race) there's nothing in the `resource.in_use != 0` case that could cause that value to change.  ie. it could change it to something along the lines of:

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if (resource.in_use != 0) {
        i = 1000;
        break;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&resource[i].lock);
    if (resource.in_use == 0) {
        resource.in_use = 1;
        resource.value = toInsert;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource[i].lock);
        return;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&resource[i].lock);
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is making more sense now. Sure enough, I had a typo in my original post. I had forgotten to include the indices. So I don't think the specific rewrite you suggest would occur. But I understand that undefined behavior is undefined behavior. I'll have to go dig through the spec to find it exactly. Do you happen to have a link?

Comment: @RyanMarcus: [4.11 Memory Synchronization](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_11).